# Selecting columns in R dataframe based on values of column in other dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have two dataframes as u can see below.

```
  #Dataframe 1
    colname value
    col1    0.45
    col2    -0.2
    col3    -0.4
    col4    0.1

#Dataframe 2
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    5    9    5
45   29   43   9
34   33   56   3
2    67   76   1
```

What I want to do is to firstly select all columns of dataframe 1 that have a value > 0.3 or value < -0.3. The second thing I want is to select all column from dataframe 2 that match this condition. So the columns col1 and col3  of dataframe2 should be selected into a new dataframe like below.

```
col1  col3 
1     9   
45    43   
34    56   
2     76
```

The solution I thought about is to firstly select the relevant columns as u can see in the code below.

```
library(sqldf)
features = sqldf('select colname from dataframe1 where value > 0.3 or value < -0.3')
```

After this to build a string in a for loop that should look like below. And paste this in a `sqldf` query to select to right columns from dataframe2. However I dont know how to build this string. U guys know this or have a other solution?

```
  stringValue = "col1, col3, col4"
   sprintf("SELECT %s FROM dataframe2", stringValue)
```

Comment: `paste(features, collapse=",")` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current `dataframe1` only `col1` and `col3` will get selected.

```
library(sqldf)
features = sqldf('select colname from dataframe1 where value > 0.3 or value < -0.3')
sqldf(sprintf("SELECT %s FROM dataframe2", paste0(features$colname, collapse = ", ")))


#       col1 col3
#    1    1    9
#    2   45   43
#    3   34   56
#    4    2   76
```

**data**

```
#Dataframe 1
dataframe1 <- read.table(text = 'colname value
    col1    0.45
                         col2    -0.2
                         col3    -0.4
                         col4    0.1', header = T, sep = "")

#Dataframe 2
dataframe2 <- read.table(text = 'col1 col2 col3 col4
1    5    9    5
45   29   43   9
34   33   56   3
2    67   76   1', header = T, sep = "")
```

Comment: The last `sqldf` line can be written ``fn$sqldf("SELECT `toString(features$colname)` FROM dataframe2")`` or as `cols <- toString(features$colname); fn$sqldf("SELECT $cols FROM dataframe2")`

Comment: Also the first `sqldf` statement could be written `features <- sqldf('select colname from dataframe1 where not value between -0.3 and 0.3')`

Answer (score 1):

A base R way of doing this:

```
> mask <- dataframe1$value > 0.3 | dataframe1$value < -0.3
> dataframe2[, mask]

  col1 col3
1    1    9
2   45   43
3   34   56
4    2   76
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` (not sure if it is relevant), you can do:

```
df2 %>% 
select(one_of(df1 %>% filter(value > 0.3 | value < -0.3) %>% pull(colname) %>% as.character()))
```

This works by selecting column names that match `one_of` the strings from `df1` that works within the `filter`.